# Kubernetes dashboard through kubectl proxy - port confusion

Tags: kubernetes

I have seen that the standard way to access http services through the kubectl proxy is the following:
`http://api.host/api/v1/namespaces/NAMESPACE/services/SERVICE_NAME:SERVICE_PORT/proxy/`

Why is it that the kubernetes-dashboard uses `https:kubernetes-dashboard:` for `SERVICE_NAME:SERVICE_PORT`?

I would assume from the following that it would be `kubernetes_dashboard:443`.

```
kubectl -n kube-system get service kubernetes-dashboard -o wide
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE   SELECTOR
kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.233.50.212   <none>        443:31663/TCP   15d   k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
```

Additionally, what is the meaning of the port show `443:31663` when all other services will just have `x/TCP` (*x* being one number instead of *x*:*y*)

Lastly, `kubectl cluster-info` will show

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://x.x.x.x:x
kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://x.x.x.x:x/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy
```

I have created a simple service but it does not show here and I am confused how to determine what services show here or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it that the kubernetes-dashboard uses
>   https:kubernetes-dashboard: for SERVICE_NAME:SERVICE_PORT?
>
> Additionally, what is the meaning of the port show 443:31663 when all
>   other services will just have x/TCP (x being one number instead of
>   x:y)

As described in [Manually constructing apiserver proxy URLs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls), the default way is

```
http://kubernetes_master_address/api/v1/namespaces/namespace_name/services/service_name[:port_name]/proxy
```

> By default, the API server proxies to your service using http. To use
>   https, prefix the service name with https::

`http://kubernetes_master_address/api/v1/namespaces/namespace_name/services/https:service_name:[port_name]/proxy`

The supported formats for the name segment of the URL are:

`<service_name>` - proxies to the default or unnamed port using http

`<service_name>:<port_name>` - proxies to the specified port using http

`https:<service_name>:` - proxies to the default or unnamed port using https (note the trailing colon)

`https:<service_name>:<port_name>` - proxies to the specified port using https

Next:

> I have created a simple service but it does not show here and I am
>   confused how to determine what services show here or not.

What is what I found and tested for you:

[cluster-info API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cluster-info):

Display addresses of the master and services with label **kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true** To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.

So, as soon as you add `kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"` label - the service starts to be seen under `kubectl cluster-info`.

BUT!! There is an expected behavior when you see that you service  disappear from output in couple of minutes. Explanation has been found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/1849#issuecomment-294100681) - I only copy paste it here for future reference.

> The other part is the addon manager. It uses this annotation to
>   synchronizes the cluster state with static manifest files. The
>   behavior was something like this:

1) addon manager reads a yaml from disk -> deploys the contents

2) addon manager reads all deployments from api server with annotation cluster-service:true -> deletes all that do not exist as files

**As a result, if you add this annotation, addon manager will remove dashboard after a minute or so.**

So,

**dashboard is deployed after cluster creation -> annotation should not be set:**
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/b98d167dadaafb665a28091d1e975cf74eb31c94/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

**dashboard is deployed part of cluster creation -> annotation should be set:**
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/dashboard/dashboard-controller.yaml

At least this was the behavior some time ago. I think kubeadm does not use addon-manager. But it is still part of kube-up script.

Solution for this behavior also exists: add additional label `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists`

Explanation is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/1849#issuecomment-337480580)

You final service should look like:

```
# ------------------- Dashboard Service ------------------- #

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard



kubectl get svc kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"EnsureExists","k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard","kubernetes.io/cluster-service":"true"},"name":"kubernetes-dashboard","namespace":"kube-system"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":443,"targetPort":8443}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"}}}
  labels:
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"



kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://*.*.*.*
...
kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://*.*.*.*/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy
...
```

Comment: If the name is `name: kubernetes-dashboard` and `port: 443`, instead of `https:kubernetes-dashboard:` should it not be `kubernetes-dashboard:443`?

Also, I am aware of the kubectl get `services --all-namespaces`, but my question was for the services that were showing on `kubectl cluster-info` instead of listing services in general.

Comment: completely rewrote the answer for you